# Зачем нужен атрибут [JsonProperty]

Tags: c#, json, парсер

Приветствую! Собственно вопрос в заголовке - для чего используется атрибут `[JsonProperty("PropertyName")]` в классе при сериализации или десериализации ?
Например если получать из строки обьект вот так :

```
RootObject Responce = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText("path"));
```

то результат будет одним и тем же - что есть в классе `RootObject` модификаторы `[JsonProperty("PropertyName")]` над полями, что нет. Так зачем они ?

Comment: если у вас свойство `A` класса будет помечено с `[JsonProperty("B")]`, то вероятно в json оно запишется как `B` а не `А`, и так же будет извлечено обратно, не?

Comment: @teran а что мешает назвать свойство сразу `B` ?

Comment: @Сергей, например _правила именования_ могут отличаться в C# и js.

Comment: @Grundy т.е. кроме переименования и добавки статических свойств больше не для чего ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Атрибут [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm),  очевидно, используется для замены имени свойств и параметров конструктора.

> Maps a JSON property to a .NET member or constructor parameter.

Для примера тестовый класс с единственным свойством

```
class Test  {        
    public int x { get; set; }
}
```

создаем экземпляр, сериализуем:

```
var x = new Test() { x = 1 };
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);      
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

имеем результат `{"x":1}`

Добавляем атрибут

```
[JsonProperty("y")]
public int x { get; set; }
```

повторяем операцию, результатом будет строка `{"y":1}`

Поскольку `JSON` это прежде всего формат передачи данных, то подобное переименование может иметь смысл для согласования имен свойств в разных системах, либо, когда имя свойства имеет зарезервированное значение, когда формат данных меняется, а рефакторинг не целесообразен, задавать обязательность/необязательность полей, значения по умолчанию (если при десериалзации их не было), указывать, будут ли сохранены `null` значения и т.п.

[Согласно документации](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

> `JsonProperty` может использовать в следующих случаях:
>
> - По умолчанию свойство JSON-объекта будет иметь то же название, что и .Net класса. Данный атрибут позволяет изменить это название.
> - `JsonProperty` показывает, что свойство должно быт сериализовано, если объект сериализуется выборочно, а не целиком.
> - Может включать не публичные (`public`) свойства для сераилизации и обратно.
> - Указания способов обработки null-значений, значенйи по умолчанию, обязательных полей, имен типов и т.п.
> - Изменения [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm)
> - It can be used to customize the property's collection items JsonConverter, type name handling, and reference handling.

Comment: Да вы правы это может иметь смысл. Но оказывается не только для этого.

Comment: случайно обнаружил еще одно интересное св-во применяемое к статичным полям.

Comment: @Сергей дополнил чутка ответ

Comment: странно что про static не слова в документации

Comment: @Сергей в другом месте где нибудь написано, что static поля (и приватные к примеру тоже) не сериализуеются по умолчанию, но если пометить атрибутом то будут. В общем все что помечено этим атрибутом, то сериализуется.

Comment: словом очень полезный модификатор. интересно единственный ли?

Comment: в ответе приведена ссылка и на другие атрибуты https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm

Comment: класс. снимаю шляпу!)

Answer (score 8):

Кроме исчерпывающего ответа уважаемого @terran у модификатора есть еще одно интересное свойство : статичные поля класса также будут записаны в JSON при сериализации, чего не произойдет без модификатора.

```
class Person
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
}
```

При попытке получить строку обычным конвертером `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` статичного поля в нем не окажется. Результат :

```
{}
```

Совсем иначе если добавить модификатор :

```
class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("name:")]
    public static string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Результат :

```
{"name:":"Ivan"}
```